# Boost pool singleton RequestedSize setup

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

I am trying to use [boost::singleton_pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/singleton_pool.html) for memory pooling. I need it to solve the following problem:

In my app I allocate occasionally memory for objects of fixed number of bytes. Then at some point I deallocate those (also occasionally one by one). There is always at most `N` (set at compile time) number of the allocated objects in memory. Each time one of those ends its lifetime it gets deallocated. So my question is, given the mentioned object name is `demo_block`, should I specify `RequestedSize` to be `N * sizeof(demo_block)`? That's like this:

```
 struct MyOrderTag{};
typedef boost::singleton_pool<MyOrderTag,sizeof(demo_block) * MaxObjects> MyMemPool;
```

or just a size of a single object?

```
struct MyOrderTag{};
typedef boost::singleton_pool<MyOrderTag,sizeof(demo_block)> MyMemPool;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the size like this:

```
struct MyOrderTag{};
typedef boost::singleton_pool<MyOrderTag,sizeof(demo_block)> MyMemPool;
```

You can take a look at the pool [interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool.html) which singleton_pool is using. When the pool is created, it receives the size to allocate. That is why the different malloc functions of the pool interface do not take a size in parameter, it is fixed at pool creation.

Comment: So that means the pool will allocate as much space as needed to hold the memory for all allocated objects?How can I restrict that size?

Comment: You can specify an allocator for the class. By default is uses the default new and delete but you could write one that limit the number of allocation to your defined value.